# Why Google Map Does Not Show Up When Opening A Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that when anyone click on http://millenniumedical.com/contact-us.html the Google Map at the bottom does not load. However, it loads when the page is refreshed. What am I missing in the code?

Head Tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Millennium Medical Group, PC - Contact Us</title>
<meta name="description" content="Millennium Medical Group, PC" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Medical, Doctor, Pain Management, Chronic Pain, Surgery,   Anesthesia, Radiology, Physician, MD, New Jersey, North" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen, print" />

<!-- Google Analytics-->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-40435642-1', 'millenniumedical.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics-->

</head>
```

Body Tag

```
<body>
<div id="header"><img src="images/header_2012.gif" alt="" style="padding-left: 10px;"    usemap="#header2012" /> <map name="header2012" id="header2012"> 
<area shape="rect" coords="20,30,470,100" href="index.html" />
</map>
<div id="nav">
<div id="about"><a href="about-our-practice.html"><img src="images/spacer.gif"  width="180" height="35" alt="" /></a></div>
<div id="team"><a href="our-medical-team.html"><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="171"  height="35" alt="" /></a></div>
<div id="services"><a href="patient-services.html"><img src="images/spacer.gif"  width="162" height="35" alt="" /></a></div>
<div id="testimonials"><a href="testimonials.html"><img src="images/spacer.gif"  width="137" height="35" alt="" /></a></div>
<div id="contact" class="current"><a href="contact-us.html"><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="125" height="35" alt="" /></a></div>
<div id="info"><a href="helpful-information.html"><img src="images/spacer.gif"  width="185" height="35" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Millennium Medical Group, PC<br /> www.millenniumedical.com<br /> Tel:  866-929-PAIN<br /> <br />
<ul>
<li><a href="about-our-practice.html">About Our Practice</a></li>
<li><a href="our-medical-team.html">Our Medical Team</a></li>
<li><a href="patient-services.html">Patient Services</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="helpful-information.html">Helpful Information</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="copy" class="nobannerabove">
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<p><strong>Phone:</strong> <span style="font-weight: ligther;">866-929-PAIN</span><br  />  <strong>Email: </strong> <a  href="mailto:millenniumedicalpc@gmail.com">millenniumedical@gmail.com</a><br /><br /> We  are proud to consult and provide care for patients in convenient locations in Bergen, <!-- Essex,--> Hudson and Passaic counties. Click on an office address to view it's location on  the map.</p>
<ul class="maplocations" style="line-height: 25px;">
<li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.93 8934,-74.043045&amp;spn=0.181544,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=0004ea70aa24cca80f120&amp;outp ut=embed" target="googlemap">165 Main Street, Hackensack, NJ 07601</a></li>
<li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.88 7563,-73.987427&amp;spn=0.181685,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=0004ea70eaf4d2e5a61c3&amp;outp ut=embed" target="googlemap">596 Anderson Avenue, Suite 104, Cliffside Park, NJ 07010</a>   </li>
<li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.78 3141,-74.142609&amp;spn=0.181972,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=0004ea70ef9e045ba241a&amp;outp ut=embed" target="googlemap">119-137 Clifford Street, Suite 101, Newark, NJ 07105</a></li>
<li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.71 5517,-74.184494&amp;spn=0.182157,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=0004ea70f27e52b9c7918&amp;outp ut=embed" target="googlemap">925 Elizabeth Ave, Elizabeth, NJ 07201</a></li>
<li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.91 5588,-74.104156&amp;spn=0.181608,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=0004ea70f792d96eb5d77&amp;outp ut=embed" target="googlemap">625 Main Ave, Passaic, NJ 07055</a></li>
<li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.97 3159,-74.123383&amp;spn=0.18145,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=0004ea70f96cc2074adf0&amp;outpu t=embed" target="googlemap">680 Broadway, Paterson, NJ 07514</a></li>
</ul>
<iframe name="googlemap" width="540" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src"https://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.78 886,-74.09729&amp;spn=0.181956,0.370789&amp;z=11&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />  <small>View <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms? msid=213518179157922455669.0004ea70aa23b07a32d71&amp;msa=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=40.78 886,-74.09729&amp;spn=0.181956,0.370789&amp;z=11&amp;source=embed"  style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Millennium Medical Group Pc</a> in a larger  map</small>

</div>

<div id="footerbar"><span class="disclaimer">DISCLAIMER: The information presented on  this web site is intended for informational and educational purposes only. This is not a replacement or substitute for professional medical advice. Please seek the adivce of a  physician or medical professional concerning your specific medical condition or questions.    </span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an `=` in your `<iframe>` tag.

[Validating your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmillenniumedical.com%2Fcontact-us.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) would have caught this and other errors.

Comment: Wow, thanks for noticing this! I should have validated the code first, but huge thanks for the help!